# How to enable broker security in confluent-kafka?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

i am trying to enable security in kafka.

i tried with **Apache Kafka** it worked fine,But now we are using confluent-platform docker image to get all confluent services.

Here i dont know how to enable the kafka ssl security ?

i checked in broker container etc/kafka/ but i didnt no in which file we need change the properties

because there are two files **1)Kafka.properties 2)server.properties**

so i am so much confused,

can anyone share your suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

What docker image do you use? Please, make sure that you are pulling them from [hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka)

Usually, the configuration file for Apache Kafka brokers is `server.properties`. You do not need to inject the whole config file though. You can configure it with environment variables passed to the container. Please, see [cp-demo/blob/6.1.0-post/docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo/blob/6.1.0-post/docker-compose.yml) as an example.

Comment: Thanka @Kikulikov i am using confluent platform docker image from this https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/tree/5.5.1-post/cp-all-in-one,here if we navigate to /etc/kafka in broker container i have two properties file like i said

Comment: Right. It is `/etc/kafka/kafka.properties`. You can check it with a `ps` command (e.g. `ps afx | grep kafka`). The last parameter is the configuration file.